# Storing attribute twice with composition in python - is it memory inefficient?

Tags: python, performance, oop, memory, composition

I have a class structure like the following,

```
class binomial():

  def __init__(self, theta):
    self.theta = theta

class beta_binomial():
  def __init__(self, theta, beta):
    self.b = binomial(theta)
    self.theta = self.b.theta
    self.beta = beta
```

I like this structure because I can directly access `theta` and `beta` with the following,

```
bb = beta_binomial(np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3]), np.array([0.35, 0.15, 0.53, 0.83]))
bb.theta, bb.beta
```

However, I'm wondering if this is memory inefficient as `theta` is both an attribute of `binomial` and `beta_binomial`. In other words, `bb.theta` and `bb.b.theta` return the same thing. I know Python does some clever things to reduce inefficiencies like this, but I'm not sure if it applies here. This could matter if `theta` is a very large array (which it can be).

Comment: Well, yes. You are using 50% more memory for attributes than you strictly need to. Whether such inefficiency *matters* is another question: how many instances of `beta_binomial` do you have at one time?

Comment: Regarding Python's cleverness, both `self.theta` and `self.b.theta` refer to the same object, but there's still the overhead of having two references where one would suffice.

Comment: `theta` can get quite big. Using `id(bb.b.theta)` and `id(bb.theta)` returns the same memory address. It seems the inefficiency you're talking about is quite negligible. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: Correct. Also, there's a big difference between having one instance of `beta_binomial` (where you are only "wasting"  8 bytes or so) and having thousands of them, where you would still only be wasting kilobytes of memory.

Comment: In addition to my answer, having `beta_binomial` inherit from `binomial` might be an option. In that case, there would only be one reference to `theta` in the object.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than store `theta` as an instance attribute, make it a property.

```
class beta_binomial:
    def __init__(self, theta, beta):
        self.b = binomial(theta)
        self.beta = beta

    @property
    def theta(self):
        return self.b.theta
```

This uses less memory per instance, but at the cost of slightly slower access.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not memory inefficient other than the negligible overhead of having duplicate references (which can stack up if you have many instances). One can use the [id()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_id.asp#:%7E:text=The%20id()%20function%20returns,object%20when%20it%20is%20created.) function to see that `bb.theta` and `bb.b.theta` have the same memory address.

```
bb = beta_binomial(np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3]), np.array([0.35, 0.15, 0.53, 0.83]))
id(bb.theta) == id(bb.b.theta)
```

Returns `true`.